# Why doesn't my view update when adding items to my DataBound collection?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

My simplified code looks like this:

**Model**

```
class Playlist : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Track> _tracks;
    public ObservableCollection<Track> Tracks
    {
        get
        {
            return _tracks;
        }
        set
        {
            _tracks = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Tracks");
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class HubPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Playlist _currentPlaylist;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    public Playlist CurrentPlaylist
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentPlaylist;
        }
        set
        {
            _currentPlaylist = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentPlaylist");
        }
    }

    public HubPageViewModel()
    {
        _currentPlaylist = new Playlist();
    }
}
```

**View**

```
public sealed partial class HubPage : Page
{
    private HubPageViewModel _hubPageViewModel;

    public HubPageViewModel HubPageViewModel
    { 
        get
        {
            return _hubPageViewModel;
        }
    }

    public HubPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        viewModel = new HubPageViewModel();
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Page
x:Class="MyProject.HubPage"
DataContext="{Binding HubPageViewModel , RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<snip>

    <HubSection x:Uid="HubSection5" Header="Now Playing"
                    DataContext="{Binding CurrentPlaylist}" HeaderTemplate="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderTemplate}">
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListView 
                    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemListViewSection5"
                    AutomationProperties.Name="Items In Group"
                    SelectionMode="None"
                    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Tracks}"
                    ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick"
                    ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,27.5" Holding="StackPanel_Holding">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
 <snip>
```

Why doesn't my view update when I add or remove a `Track` to my `Playlist`?

Comment: I think you misunderstand meaning of `model` and `viewmodel`.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I might, but do remember that this is simplified code.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant XAML too please?

Comment: @DecadeMoon Added it to my question.

Comment: I mean that the viewmodel must notify about its changes but model must provide persistence.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan So my VM must also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: Yes. And it is not necessary the model to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Also you haven't show how you define `PlayList` and `DefaultViewModel`.

Comment: Here is [Josh Smith's good article about MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Thank you for the link. What do you mean 'how I define `Playlist` and `DefaultViewModel`'?

Comment: Regardless of whether or not OP has implemented MVVM correctly, as long as the ListView's ItemsSource is bound to an ObservableCollection instance, it should update when an item is added to that collection. We need to work out why this isn't happening here.

Comment: I can't find declaration of `DefaultViewModel` in you post.

Comment: Do existing items get displayed in the list, but the list won't update when an item is added to the collection? Are you getting any binding errors in the output window?

Comment: @Hamlet `DefaultViewModel` is provided with the Pivot and Hub app project templates.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I'm sorry, added it to my view. `private readonly ObservableDictionary defaultViewModel = new ObservableDictionary();`

Comment: @DecadeMoon Indeed. I can see my items when I update my `defaultViewModel["CurrentPlaylist"]` manually, but not when adding or removing tracks to my playlist.

Comment: @DecadeMoon there are more subtle (or not) requirements for binding to work. `ObservableCollection` just notify about collection changes but is must properly bound to ItemSource at first.

Comment: You can't bound to private member.

Comment: @Hamlet It's a public property. Create a new WP 8.1 Pivot app project and you'll see how `DefaultViewModel` is implemented.

Comment: @DecadeMoon I've updated my code. I now use my VM as DataContext and I still don't get updates through. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem: I wasn't removing or adding tracks correctly.
I modified them on the model, and not on my Collection property.

Once I modified my property, the events got through and my View is updated.